# Setting an EditText and a Button on top of a ListView

Tags: android-layout

I'm doing my first tutorial on Android and trying to display a EditText with a Button on top of a ListView.
This is where I've got, but the ListView is not showing.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

     <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/new_name"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"/>

     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_plus" 
        android:onClick="openActivity"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:id="@+id/listview1" 
       android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
       >          
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know something simple is missing but can't get there.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not showing even if you populate it with data from your adapter?

Comment: No, even with data. If I remove the LinearLayout all together, the ListView shows up with populated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change one parameter of your `LinearLayout`:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Your `RelativeLayout` is vertical and by setting height of `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` it's trying to allocate all the vertical space of the screen